# Typeahead Bloodhound autocomplete cant work with json objects

Tags: typeahead.js, bloodhound

Desperately trying to figure out why autocomplete not working with json objects

```
(function($){

    let $country = $('#country');

    let countries = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: '../../data/countries.json'
    });

    $country.typeahead({
        name: 'countries',
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    },{
        source: countries,
        templates: {
            empty: ['No data'].join('\n'),
            suggestion: {
                function (data) {
                    return '<ul><li>'+data.name+'</li></ul>';
                }
            }
        }
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Everything working with json like ["item1","item2","Item3"]
But not with [{"name":"item1"},{"name":"item2"},{"name":"item3"}]

My json is correct, I even tried to use this one: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/nba.json

When using associative array always getting "No data".

Also tried this one:

```
prefetch: {
            url: '../../data/countries.json',
            filter: function(list) {
                return $.map(list, function(item) {
                    return {
                        name: item.name,
                        code: item.code
                    };
                });
            }
        }
```

Data is prefetching, but still no suggestion.

Of course after every edit I cleaning my local storage.

Also tried using Handlebars

```
name: 'countries',
        source: countries,
        display: 'name',
        templates: {
            empty: ['No data'].join('\n'),
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p><strong>{{name}}</strong></p>')
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I figureout it, still not sure why...

```
datumTokenizer: function (d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); }
```

Instead of

```
datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
```

So full working code is

```
(function($){

    let $country = $('#country');

    let countries = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function (d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: {
            url: '../../data/countries.json',
            filter: function(list) {
                return $.map(list, function(item) {
                    return {
                        name: item.name,
                        code: item.code
                    };
                });
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });

    $country.typeahead({
        name: 'countries',
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    },{
        source: countries,
        display: function(data) { return data.name },
        templates: {
            empty: ['No data'].join('\n'),
            suggestion: function (data) {
                return '<ul><li>'+data.name+'</li></ul>';
            }
        }
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Well this may not be a complete explanation. If the returned JSON is an array of strings, it is pretty much straightforward for the engine. Otherwise Bloodhound suggestion engine should know datumTokenizer so that it knows what to suggest based on user query. In your case returned JSON is an object array. So the search can be based on name or code. You provide this information in your datumTokenizer so that suggestions will be matched accordingly.